# string[] inside of list causing problems

Tags: c#, arrays, list, search, foreach

I am creating a journal that consists of an array inside of a list, the array being every new entry and the list being the journal. Here's how I've tried to solve it so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;                

namespace Journal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int menuChoice = 0;
            List<string[]> journal = new List<string[]>();

            while (menuChoice != 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t===Journal===");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[1] New entry in the journal");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[2] Search entry in the journal");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[3] Show contents of the journal");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[4] Exit");
                Console.Write("\tChoose: ");

                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menuChoice);
                {
                    switch (menuChoice)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                string[] entry = new string[3];
                                DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
                                entry[0] = Convert.ToString(time);
                                Console.Write("\n\tWrite your title: ");
                                entry[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.Write("\n\tWrite your new entry: ");
                                entry[2] = Console.ReadLine();
                                journal.Add(entry);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.Write("\n\tSearch entry in the journal: ");
                            string searchTerm = Console.ReadLine();
                            for (int i = 0; i < journal.Count; i++)

                                if (journal[i].Contains(searchTerm))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(journal[i]);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tYour search was not found.");
                                }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tJournal:");
                            foreach (string[] item in journal)
                                Console.WriteLine("\n\t" + item);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've had a great deal of trouble trying to make this work, which it still doesn't. What I'm trying to do is use up 3 index spaces in the array for the time, title and text and then putting those 3 combined into the list so they become a single element in the list so when I search for the title they come as a group.

I've tried to use a normal string list when declaring the journal but then I can't add the array into it without having to specify which index to insert. When I change the type of the list to a string[] the foreach loops stop working because they can't convert a string[] to a string, so then I change the string inside the foreach loop to a string[] and now all I get when I try to write everything out or search is "System.String[]".

That's pretty much where I'm at right now, so if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or show me how I can solve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a `JournalEntry` class, instead of using a string array for this. It'll make your code much less confusing to work with: `entry.Time`, `entry.Title` and `entry.Content` versus `entry[0]`, `entry[1]` and `entry[2]`.

Comment: Also note that you're not calling `string.Contains`, but `Enumerable.Contains` (a Linq method that operates on collections such as arrays, lists, etc.). This causes a search to check whether the time, title or content of an entry is exactly equal to the given search term, instead of checking whether the title or content contain the search term. `"abc".Contains("b")` returns true, whereas `(new string[] { "abc" }).Contains("b")` returns false, because that array doesn't contain a `"b"` string.

Answer (score 0):

`journal` is a list of strings arrays. `journal[i]` is an array of strings. To print out the values in a string array, you need to loop through that array.

```
if (journal[i].Contains(searchTerm))
{
     for (int j = 0; j < journal[i].Count; j++)
         Console.WriteLine(journal[i][j]);
}
```

Or as a `foreach`

```
foreach(string item in journal[i])
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using linq, you can yield one List from a list of sub-Lists:

```
foreach(var item in journal.SelectMany(x => x))
{
   // item is string
}
```

you need to add `using System.Linq;` of course.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve the problem would be to create a `JournalEntry` class with `Title`, `Date`, and `Body` properties. In that class you can override `ToString` to produce formatted output.

Without creating a class, the easiest way to solve this problem is with the judicious application of a small amount of LINQ. You can also use `String.Join` to combine the string array into a single string for `Console.WriteLine`.

To search for the first entry with a title that contains the search term:

```
var selected = journal.FirstOrDefault(item => item[1].Contains(searchTerm));
if (selected != null)
{
    // selected is the first string[] with a title containing the search term.
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", result));
}
```

To search for *all* entries that have a title containing the search term:

```
var selected = journal.Where(item => item[1].Contains(searchTerm));
foreach (var result in selected)
{
   // result is the string[] journal entry
   Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", result));
}
```